# Calculating $C_v$ of a canonical ensemble

Tags: statistical-mechanics

I am writing code to find the heat capacity $C_v$ of a canonical $NVT$ ensemble. We know that,
$$C_v = \frac{\langle U^2 \rangle - \langle U \rangle ^2}{k_B T^2}$$

I have written a Metropolis algorithm to see how a standard $NVT$ system evolves.
This is how I plan to calculate $\langle U \rangle$:
$$\langle U \rangle = \frac{\sum_{m} P_m U_m}{\sum_m P_m} \quad \quad \ldots(1)$$
where $m$ is a microstate the system as determined by my Metropolis algorithm, and $$P_m = e^{-\frac{U_m}{k_BT}}$$

Same applies for $\langle U^2 \rangle$, except in I replace $U_m$ with $U^2_m$ in equation $(1)$.

Is this the right approach?

Comment: Well, as long as you avoid pitfalls of Metropolis algorithm sampling, why not? Do you have a specific concern?

Comment: @acarturk Um, I was wondering if I was doing it right...

Answer (score 1):

The $P_m$ factors are unnecessary. Why? Because a state $i$ will be returned $\approx Np_i$ times in $N$ samples. Since you have a record of samples (indexed by $m$ and not to be confused with $i$, the state index) the sample record itself have the probability distribution embedded in it. You should just use

$$\langle U \rangle = \frac{1}{N} \sum_m u_m$$

You can see this quantitatively by realizing $p_i$ (the probability $\exp(-u_i/kT)/Z$) can be expressed as

$$p_i = \frac{1}{N} \sum_m \delta_{u_i,u_m}$$

and

$$\langle U \rangle = \sum_i u_i p_i = \sum_i u_i \frac{1}{N} \sum_m \delta_{u_i,u_m} = \sum_i \sum_m u_i \frac{1}{N} \delta_{u_i,u_m} = \sum_m \sum_i u_i \frac{1}{N} \delta_{u_i,u_m} = \frac{1}{N} \sum_m u_m$$

(in the last equality: $\sum_i u_i \delta_{u_i,u_m} = u_m$ since the samples correspond to exactly one state).

I don't want to check if your eq. (1) is correct or not, but this way is simpler to implement anyway.